# Limiting List Iterations in a For Loop (Closest To Player)

Tags: c#, optimization, xna, collision

I have a `List<Collider> colliders` which is for a tile map.

One approach that I thought of is to check the full list for all colliders' positions, compare to player's position, then add closest colliders to a temporary list for faster iteration. Only doing this once every 100ms would decrease performance loss. But I'd imagine there are better ways than this, right?

I've read a different post on here for collision optimization, and it mentioned using a "CPU Budget", which I intend to implement for this and others as well. I have not read about threading yet.

Shorter question: **How can I limit the maximum iterations to only the colliders closest to player?**

Comment: Did your tile map is also a list? If so why are not use one or two dimentional array?

Comment: I do that currently(both layers and collision), but due to some other complications/needs I have(and want) to switch over to a list of colliders. But thanks for mentioning that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the number of colliders for check you can previously excluded them from the list of candidates. Keep colliders in **Dictionary colliders**, and also create a second **Dictionary > collidersByChunks**. As a key in the second dictionary use coordinate of chunk, and as the value use sublist of colliders. Something like this:

```
class ColliderManager
{
    Dictionary<TKey, Collider> colliders;
    Dictionary<Vector2, List<TKey>> collidersByChunks;

    public void AddCollider(TKey pKey, Collider pCOllider)
    {
        this.colliders.Add(pKey, pCollider);

        foreach(Vector2 chunkCoord in this.GetChunkCoords(pCollider.Rectangle))
        {
            List<TKey> collidersAtChunk = null;
            if(!this.collidersByChunks.TryGetValue(chunkCoord, out collidersAtChunk))
            {
                collidersAtChunk = new List<TKey>();
                this.collidersByChunks.Add(chunkCoords, collidersAtChunk);
            }

            collidersAtChunk.Add(pKey, pCollider);
        }
    }

    private Vector2[] GetChunkCoords(Rectangle pRectangle)
    {
        // return all chunks pRectangle intersects
    }
}
```

When checking determine which chunks crosses the scanned object and compares it with colliders only from that chunks.

Comment: Good answer, simple but effective.

Answer (score 1):

I found using List.Where() works best in this case. List of 100,000 colliders (somewhat extreme, however pretty likely on a 512x512 map), using:

```
foreach (TestCollider test in integers.Where(c => c.IsInRange() == true)) { }
```

Using `Stopwatch`, iterated through 1,000 times, with a `range` of 20:

- List of 10,000: 0ms always
- List of 50,000: 2ms avg.
- List of 100,000: 4ms avg.
- List of 250,000: 12 ms avg.

If anyone has any suggestions for improvements, I'd be very happy to update this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
foreach (Collider collider in colliders.OrderBy(c => c.Position - player.Position))
{
    // The tiles closest to the player should be at the start
    if (collider.Rectangle.Intersects(player.Rectangle))
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do here
        Break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try this soon and get back to you. One observation: will this still iterate through tiles far away from the player? If so, I'd need a way to limit that.

Comment: I've added a break so that as soon as an intersection is found (which should be the one of the first checked) the loop is broken out of. This will limit the number of times Intersects() is called, thus speeding up your game.

Comment: Just tested it. Putting in the `break;` stops other collisions from taking place. This doesn't work, especially on corners. With a  512x512 map and the assumption that it has 250,000 collisions, this method would take 71-74 milliseconds per call to update. Also it is still iterating through the entire list. It's not really the Intersects() method which is the performance issue, it's the amount of iterations. I need a way to limit that.

Comment: Ok,  I didn't appreciate that there would be so many tiles! Linq will be slower than just performing a normal loop against all tiles as linq methods typically iterate through all items in a collection, return a new collection with your specified criteria, then you iterare with your collision checks.

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that to begin with!